# How to relabel x-axis in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

It's not a xlabel or ylabel question. I want to relabel numbers on the graph so that the x-axis is labeled as `category1` `category2` instead of a list of numbers `1` `2` `3` etc., because my independent variables are categories instead of consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `set` command. If you have 3 categories, then you could use:

```
set(gca,'XTick', 1:3)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'category 1','category 2','category 3'})
```

In this example, `gca` returns the handle of the current axes and  `XTick` and `XTickLabel` are the properties of the axes.

Comment: How to let it label from x=1 instead of 0?

Comment: Each label specified in the second command corresponds to the tick index in the first command. So three ticks means three labels. Just set the first label to 0 and the second and third to your category names.